# How can I write guard-rubocop results in a file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, guard, rubocop

I have implemented guard-rubocop gem. I tried the same gem without guard. Without guard  I could write the results in a file(rubocop -o/--out) [rubocop without guard](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) . But with guard I am unable to find options [rubocop with guard](https://github.com/yujinakayama/guard-rubocop). Can anybody teach me how to write guard-rubocop results in a file??

Answer (score 1):

have you tried

```
guard :rubocop, cli: ['--out /path/to/output/file'] do
  # ...
end
```

as suggested in the [documentation](https://github.com/yujinakayama/guard-rubocop#options)

Comment: The following exception occurred while running guard-rubocop: /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@alo-gu/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `initialize' A JSON text must at least contain two octets! (JSON::ParserError). getting this error

Comment: My problem is, when I run guard rubocop results has to be saved in a file rather being a garbage after my command

Comment: The error I am getting again. invalid option: --out /home/user/work/projects/a/axld-guard/rubocop.txt
10:17:31 - ERROR - The following exception occurred while running guard-rubocop: /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@anon-ui-gu/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `initialize' A JSON text must at least contain two octets! (JSON::ParserError)

Comment: I've read the source of guard-rubocop and rubocop further regarding this issue. The solution I've found is the following:


`guard :rubocop, cli: ['--format', 'html', '--out', 'rubocop/index.html'] do`

You have to give all parts of the arguments separately!

Found by reading a spec file of rubocop found here: https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/b7f224b943d22125692c0c9d228feeab1871cdda/spec/rubocop/cli/cli_options_spec.rb#L917

Answer (score 1):

#### updated

If you need only rubocop output to file then here is how could be done:

```
# Guardfile

# set before guard rubocop initialisation
UI.instance_variable_set :@logger, Lumberjack::Logger.new("log/errors.log", UI.options)

guard :rubocop do
  # ...
end
```

#### Fix:

instead of hacking, Guard has a official way to set options for logger like (thanks @Netzpirat):

```
logger device: "log/errors.log"
```

Comment: The above line when added gives the debugging information only in log  file. All the errors are displayed below my command.

Comment: Guard has a `logger` DSL to configure it to log to a file, see https://github.com/guard/guard#logger No need to use `instance_variable_set`.